# Calculating factorial in C++

Tags: c++

I got 0 as output and I check the value of total inside if there it give 0 everytime

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    int n, total, a ;
    cout << "enter number for factorial :";
    cin >> n;
    a = n;
top:
    if (a != 0)
    {
        total *= a;
        a -= 1;
        
        goto top;
    }

    cout << "factorial of " << n << " is " <<total;
}
```

Comment: Labels and `goto` have their (very limited) uses. As a replacement for loops is not one of them.

Comment: Hint: the first time `total *= a;` runs, what's the current value of `total`?

Comment: `total` is uninitialized and you're using it so you have undefined behavior.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Answer (score -2):

In you declaration of `total` its is initiated with value `0`
So when it comes to the statement `total *= a` which means `total = 0 * a`

FIX:
initialize total with value 1

```cpp
int total{1};
```

or

```cpp
int total = 1;
```

Comment: This is wrong, the value of uninitialized local variables aren't zero. It's *indeterminate*.

Comment: Ehh, uninitialised variables are, generally, *not* automatically initialized to `0` - rather, they have "indeterminate" values.

Comment: Which does include the _possibility_ of them being `0`.

Comment: Now i am confused with this intermediate thing

Comment: Local variables that are not explicitly initialized are not required by the standard to hold any particular value.

Comment: In your observation the vaues were probably 0 because of your OS and not `c++` . Your OS may initialize memory pages given to your process to 0 when new memory is requested from your application to avoid leaking information from a different program that was running. This initialization only happens when the virtual memory is given the first time to your process. If the memory is reused by your process it will be whatever was in that position. Also as far as c++ is concerned it's undefined behavior to read this memory. The compiler is allowed to assume you can't look at it and optimize it away.